# Availability of form and entries

Tags: cognito-forms

I wanted to know what happens to entries after the availability of a form has ended.

Kindly confirm if they are still accessible and if so how they can be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Once a form is past its availability, the form will no longer be visible to end users. They will instead see the message that was put in place.

You will still be able to edit the form as needed on the Build page, and view already submitted entries on the Entries page.